# toolbar not showing in webview?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, coordinator-layout

I am developing an android news app and implemented toolbar as a back arrow when the user clicks  should go to the back
I am developing an android news app and implemented toolbar as a back arrow when the user clicks  should go to the back

below my `DetailActivity` where I have implemented toolbar

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import edgar.yodgorbek.sportnews.R;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.imageView)
    ImageView imageView;
    @BindView(R.id.webView)
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        String imageUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageKey");
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("urlKey");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

below my activity_detail.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you can play around the layout to see what would show...  CoordinatorLayout is a frame layout so its possible that things are covering each other... try a Linea layout and place the Webview below the tools bar